# sys_read fails in linux system call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

The `sys_read` function in my code fails when I try to run it. It returns -14. I modified the system call table, added this function to source of kernel 4.7.1(also tried other 4.x kernels) and it got compiled without any errors.

```
void rread(int fd, char *s)
{
    char buff[256];
    long n;
    n = sys_read(fd, buff, (long)sizeof buff);
    if(n <= 0) {
        printk("Unable to read %d",n);
    }
    while(n > 0) 
    {
        printk("Hello World");
        printk("%s",buff);
        n = sys_read(fd, buff, (long)sizeof buff);
    }
}

long sys_rread(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int f, i;
    f = sys_open(argv[0], O_RDONLY, S_IRWXU);
    if(f < 0)
            printk("file open error");
    rread(f, argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to test this system call using this program in the newly compiled kernel

```
int main()
{  
    printf("Invoking system call");
    char* s[] = {"/etc/adduser.conf"};
    long int ret_status = syscall(332,1,s ); // 332 is the syscall number
    if(ret_status == 0) 
         printf("System call executed correctly. Use dmesg to check \n");
    else 
         printf("System call did not execute as expected %d\n", ret_status);

     return 0;
}
```

This prints "syscall executed correctly" but in dmesg the output is "unable to read -14". How can I correct the code?

**EDIT** I searched about this problem and found [this](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0306.2/1373.html). According to the page all sys_* functions accept addresses from user space. After making changes the sys_read looks like this -

```
void rread(int fd, char *s)
{
    char buff[256];
    long n;
    mm_segment_t oldfs; 
    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS); 
    n = sys_read(fd, buff, (long)sizeof buff);
    set_fs(oldfs); 
    if(n <= 0) {
        printk("Unable to read %d",n);
    }
    while(n > 0) 
    {
        printk("%s",buff);
        oldfs = get_fs();
        set_fs(KERNEL_DS); 
        n = sys_read(fd, buff, (long)sizeof buff);
        set_fs(oldfs); 
    }
}
```

But now on executing the program, it gets stuck. To stop it I pressed Ctrl-C and checked dmesg which now shows `unable to read -512`.

Comment: `#define EFAULT  14 /* Bad address */`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Can you please explain further?

Comment: No sorry, it seems that sys_read returns minus error code, and 14 is EFAULT...

Comment: @Tsyvarev `long sys_rread(int, const char* __user)` is the same thing as what I did except that char* takes one string and char* [] is an array of strings. But how is this related to the error in sys_read?

Comment: Sorry, I have missed that you actually pass array of strings as the second argument. Nevertheless, you incorrectly access this array in the kernel space: **pointers to user space data shouldn't be deferenced directly**. That is, `argv[0]` is *generally* wrong. Instead, `copy_from_user()` should be used for copy user data to kernel space.

Comment: As you are currently debugging `sys_read()` call, I suggest you to temporary **eliminate your system call**, and do everything in the `module_init` function. Also, we don't know how you have combined the code under *EDIT* with your original code. Please, provide resulted code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have surrounded every instance of sys_read  the way I have shown in the edit.

Comment: I understand that you find the way of `surrounded every instance of sys_read the way I have shown in the edit` very obvious. But it is **very likely** that your code has very simple error (or misprint), so it behaves incorrectly. Please, edit the question and provide **exact code** which causes given behavior. Otherwise we could only **guess** a problem. E.g., your original code uses `n` variable but the code in the EDIT uses `nread`, and you incorrectly replace the first one with the second one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev edited it with complete code of function

Comment: Well, `rread` implementation seems to be correct. But what about ` `sys_open()` call? Does it actually accepts parameter ""/etc/adduser.conf""? It is possible that `sys_read` is called for remote file, that's why it waits.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I guess sys_open doesn't return any error. In sys_rread There is a check `if (f < 0)`.. If there was an error opening the file `printk` inside it would have executed.

Comment: As I said, `sys_open()` may be successfull, but it opens file which you don't expect. And `sys_read()` reads that unexpected file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev what should be done in that case?

Comment: Try to write **user space program** which uses the **same syscalls** (`open()` and `read()`) as your module, and with the **same parameters**. If the program will excibit the *same behavior* (file is opened successfully, but `read()` blocks its execution), then the problem is *not in the kernel code*. If the kernel module and the program will excibit *different behaviors*, then it will be an additional key.

Comment: @Tsyvarev tried it, works perfectly as a user space program.

Comment: In `sys_rread` function (in the kernel) output (with `printk`) value of `argv[0]` **as address**. In `main()` function (in the user program) output value of `s[0]` (also *as address*). Check, that both output give **the same address**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Both addresses are same.

Comment: AFAICS, the kernel itself uses kmalloc'ed memory and calls the ksys_xxx functions instead of sys_xxx. It kind of makes sense to protect the kernel stack, so that might be the issue.